# Minimum characters with Wildcard character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the below wild card search which looks for the following conditions.

```
$.validator.addMethod("FirstName", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{3,20}[\%\*]{0,1}$/i.test(value);
}, "For wild card search minimum of 3 characters should be entered.");

$("#frmJscsSearch").validate({
    rules : {
        FirstName : "required FirstName"
    },
});
```

1. if user enter 2 characters, its valid
2. If user enter 3 characters, its valid

How do I validate if user enter 2 characters WITH `*` then its invalid?

Comment: Not certain what Question is ?

Comment: @guest271314, please check my question

Comment: Is requirement that two characters followed by `*` character return `false` ?

Comment: Can first two characters be any characters ? Or only alphanumeric characters ? Can you update Question to describe what characters are valid input ?

Comment: @guest271314, please check the regular expression. if has required validation.

Comment: Can you describe, explain the regular expression ? What is purpose of `''-'` within character class brackets ?

Comment: What is your question ?? Your regex reduces to this `^[a-zA-Z'\s]{3,20}[%*]?$` It says match 3 to 20 alpha or single quote or whitespace, then an optional percent or asterisk. It will not match 2 plus asterisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this regex does what you want (the idea is to use alternation `|`):

```
/(^[a-z '\-]+$)|(^[a-z '-]{3,}[\%\*]$)/i
```

Your original regex was a little messy also, so I've edited it.
You can also try checking for the wrong input instead of the right one:

```
var re = /([^a-z '\-*%])|(^[\w\W]{0,2}[\*\%]&)|(^[ \-*%'])|([ \-]$)|([ \-']{2,})/i
!(re.test(value))
```

That way you can check for more specific conditions easier. The regexp above describes the following rules:

- value should contain only `a-z '-*%` characters;
- `*` or `%` should be the last symbol (if used) preceded by at least three other characters;
- value can't start with `-'*%`;
- value can't end with `-`;
- value can't contain multiple `-'` in a row.